# create a simple static page and install and start via NPM

Tags: html, node.js, npm, vue.js

I am trying create a simple HTML page with CSS/JS and use npm.

The goal is create a simple page that can be called just using "npm install" and "npm start".

For example, I'll create a page with HTML, Vue.js, CSS, etc, without backend code, and put in my github. A friend will open in his PC, and just "npm install " and "npm start" or "npm start ", and the browser will open the html page.

I have no idea what I need to do this, I never used npm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at `vue-cli`. It will allow you to do just what you want: 
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/README.md#cli

You need to have node and npm installed on your machine. To do this install:
https://nodejs.org/en/

Then in your terminal you can confirm it is installed by doing:
`node -v`
and 
`npm -v` . See npm doc if you want more info on this part: https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

Then in the terminal, install vue-cli, and create your project.

`npm install -g @vue/cli
vue create my-project`

Once the project is installed, do `npm install` followed by `npm run dev`

You should be able to see your basic vue.js app in your browser at the url show in your terminal.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer have solved my problem!! And let me add something: A friend my recommended to use "opn" to open a browser with html page after use "npm start", just configuring in package.json to use "opn('index.html'). here's the related link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn